# Where to put logic for shared items (like menus) with MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, coding-style

After I found this in our code, I realized a few things:

- "get it done now, get it right later" has a limit
- I don't actually know where this goes with MVC3

  ```
  @model int
  @using Company.Core.Logic.Financial
  @using Company.Core.Repositories
  @{
       var values = from AccountPlan e in new AccountPlanRepository().GetItemList()
                    where String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PromoCode) // filter out promotional plans
                    select new { id = e.AccountPlanId, name = e.Description };
       var items = new SelectList(values, "id", "name", Model);
   }

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, items)
  ```

This specifically is an editor template (`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AccountPlan)`), but it made me realize that I don't know where this kind of code goes for common things like menu-builders.  If you're using Layouts for MVC3 (and who isn't), where is the code for building a menu across the top based on the user's roles?  I'd imagine the view code would be iterating through pre-built menu items and HTML-ifying them, but since the Model is strong-typed, does that mean that all Models need to have knowledge of the menu items?

For once, this is where Webforms made more sense to me, since this would go in the CodeBehind, but I really want to get away from that.

edit: even though I started asking about Layout code, I'm under the assumption it works for EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates as well.  If this is an incorrect assumption, please let me know where these are supposed to go.

edit2: What I ultimately want is to have a clean, possibly even dependency-injectable place to run code that's called from an `EditorTemplate`.  Perhaps this is a case where the EditorTemplate calls immediately into a RenderAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child Actions are perfect for this scenario.  The logic required to generate the view is wrapped up in a controller action, like normal, and the view that wants to make use of the child action simply renders the action..

You can also cache these partial views, which would make sense for something like a main menu - as presumably the users permissions won't change that often.

e.g.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ViewResult MainMenu()
{
    var model = GetMenuModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

The view that wants to render the child action does so like this.

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("MainMenu", "Account"); }
```

And thus the view calling the ChildAction has no need to know what model the view requires.

There are also overloads on RenderAction, should your child action require you to pass parameters to it.

Comment: That's basically how I'm handling my main menu, and several other 'widget' type blocks of HTML rendered in different views.  This pattern works well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this solves the problem pretty well (see the marked answer, not the original question):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1566328.aspx/1?Building+ASP+NET+MVC+Master+Page+Menu+Dynamically+Based+on+the+current+User+s+Role+s+quot+

Basically, call `RenderAction(...)` and it will build the model it needs, rather than forcing you to have every model require a list of menu items.

Comment: this seems like a reasonable idea.

Comment: `RenderAction` will solve my problem if I can make editor templates behave like that as well.

Answer (score 2):

For me personally, I do a lot of menu filtering based off of active directory groups so I need to know what their access levels are across the entire application.

I create a new controller that I call ControllerBase

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    //authorization group setting an menu creation here.
    //set properties and objects to ViewBag items to access from the front end.

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and then on all the other controllers in my project I just extend from ControllerBase

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{}
```

This keeps all my server logic in one file for managing permissions and gives all my pages access to these variables when I need to hide or show different ui elements based on permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't (have to) access the Repository inside the View. That belongs in the Controller.

And the Menu is implemented in the Masterpage, you don't give much details on specifics.

Comment: i don't think this is really answering the question.  he's asking for best practices on how to get and pass global data to a _layout or some other non-view object.

Comment: The (start of the) question doesn't match the title. There is some Linq code to fill a combobox with he question "where does this go".

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, so have a +1.  I'm well aware that I (well, I didn't write this...) shouldn't be accessing repositories or for that matter new'ing anything in the View.  I'll update my question to make this a little more obvious.